# Reduce bluetoothctl verbosity

Tags: bluetooth, hci

While using interactively `bluetoothctl`, it constantly reports about RSSI changes from neighbor devices.  That's pretty anoying most of the time, as I do not care of the RSSI from my colleague's iMac while connecting my laptop to my bluetooth mouse:

```
$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -79
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -79
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -82
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -81
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -82
[Bluetooth Mouse]# devices
Device 04:xx:xx:xx:xx:37 iMac de Bernard
Device 48:xx:xx:xx:xx:86 xxxxxxxxxxx
Device 53:xx:xx:xx:xx:26 xxxxxxxxxxx
Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 xxxxxxxxxxx
Device 04:xx:xx:xx:xx:87 xxxxxxxxxxx
Device 6C:xx:xx:xx:xx:88 xxxxxxxxxxx
Device 00:xx:xx:xx:xx:32 Bluetooth Mouse
Device 44:xx:xx:xx:xx:8E xxxxxxxxxxx
Device D4:xx:xx:xx:xx:8E xxxxxxxxxxx
Device 77:xx:xx:xx:xx:77 xxxxxxxxxxx
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -82
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -80
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -79
[CHG] Device 53:xx:xx:xx:xx:26 RSSI: -84
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -79
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -79
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -78
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -80
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -82
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -77
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -84
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -78
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -82
[Bluetooth Mouse]# connect 00:xx:xx:xx:xx:32
Attempting to connect to 00:xx:xx:xx:xx:32
Connection successful
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -81
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -84
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -79
[CHG] Device 53:xx:xx:xx:xx:26 RSSI: -86
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -78
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -79
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -81
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -80
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -81
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -79
[CHG] Device 2C:xx:xx:xx:xx:B6 RSSI: -81
```

Is there a way to get rid of most of these "`[CHG]`" messages?  Kind of `bluetoothctl --quiet`?

Answer (score 11):

These change entries reporting signal strength (RSSI) show up if you ask **bluetoothctl** to scan for devices with `scan on`. Turning on scanning may happen also inadvertently if you have your `gnome-control-center bluetooth` GUI open as well, which is continuously scanning for devices.

Comment: thank you I was trying to turn it off from command line but I was getting org.bluez.Error.Failed
As you said having gnome control center gui open was triggering the scan